# Grub rescue mode, can't find .normal mod (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, grubrescue

First of all, I'll state that I'm a newbie, but I feel like I did my best and tried everything I found online before writing here.

I started using Ubuntu 16.04 while ago, I liked it, but it started to crash all the time - before I read logs or did anything I assumed I should update+upgrade, but in the middle of upgrading it crashed again - I had to do cold reboot, after that I saw >grub rescue mode.

Tried to set right prefix for my partition, did so, but from >grub rescue I couldn't manage to get `insmod` normal to work. All it said was "normal.mod" not found.

After that I booted Ubuntu live from USB, connected to internet and downloaded boot repair - Did run it (recommended mode), everything went fine and software told me to reboot - but it didn't help or solve my problem, still was at >grub rescue. [Here](http://paste2.org/6KtZyLLZ) is the boot log.

Next I tried to mount the partition with Ubuntu installed from terminal, but after typing `/sudo mount/dev/sda5` I'm getting:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

Then I tried to mount encrypted volume from command line and I'm getting other notification:

```
Error unlocking /dev/sda5: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Device /dev/sda5 is already unlocked as /dev/dm-0
```

As I said, I'm a newbie and on one side of this I like digging and learning while trying to figure it out, but on other side... I got really valuable things on that PC, I got backup, but not up to date and I lost few weeks of work.